# My site direct me to https://example.com/

Tags: wordpress

When i'm writing my website domain like mydomain.shop it give me the site https://example.com/ ,but when adding any subpage to the domain like mydomain.shop/home or mydomain.shop/contact it come right so how to make the mydomain.shop open the home page directly.

note ==> it's wordpress website

Comment: Just change every instance of `https://example.com` in your configurations and setup steps to your actual `mydomain.shop`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your post correctly, you're directed to the actual domain `https://example.com`.

I assume you used online tutorials to set up your Wordpress site. In tutorials often placeholders like "example.com" are used and you're supposed to replace them with your own domain. My guess is that you've missed one and are still using `example.com` somewhere in your config (or possibly the DNS settings).

Go over every step of your process and check to see where `example.com` is used and replace it with your domain.